# Oozie Hive Action Failed on SerDe

Tags: hadoop, hive, oozie

I get an error from oozie hive action workflow :

```
Failing Oozie Launcher, Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.HiveMain], 
      main() threw exception, org/apache/hadoop/hive/serde2/SerDe
      java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hive/serde2/SerDe
```

I'm using CDH4.2, HUE 2.2 and JSON-SerDe ([rcongiu-hive-json-serde](https://github.com/rcongiu/Hive-JSON-Serde)) for my hive table SerDe.

The Hive query script is no problem, I had successfull running it in hive console. I already set the oozie share lib. What make me strongly confuse, I get no error while submit the hive workflow with default table (not using special SerDe) but when I change to my JSON-SerDe table it always failed. the ADD JAR /path-to/serde.jar doesn't work either.

Comment: `serde.jar` must be on HDFS somewhere for Oozie to have any hope of finding it. Maybe you did this already, but I can't be sure from your question. When I needed a jar for an Oozie workflow with a Hive action, copying the jar to HDFS in the Oozie share lib worked for me `/user/oozie/share/lib/hive/serde.jar`. Doing this or adding `<file>other/path/to/jar/on/HDFS/serde.jar</file>` to the Hive action should make the jar available to Oozie. 

Or, it could be that Oozie does see `serde.jar`, but Hive can't. Unfortunately, I haven't had experience using `ADD JAR` in Hive script launched by Oozie.

Comment: @DanielKoverman yes sir i did put `serde.jar` on HDFS (sharelib & <file>serde.jar</file>) but i still get error. Strange to me when i'm missing `mysql-connector.jar`, i just put the JAR file to sharelib (HDFS) and it's work.

Comment: @mr-bagio Oh well, I was hoping I could provide you with an easy fix. Hopefully someone else will come along.

Comment: Find the MR job for this launcher, and look at the job.xml - what's the values of the classpath configuration properties (i can't remember off the top of my head what they are called, but look for the jars)

Comment: Might it relate to this [other question about SerDe problems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22324106/serde-problems-with-hive-0-12-and-hadoop-2-2-0-cdh5-0-0-beta2), even though the exception appears to mention a different class as not found?

Comment: Was this solved ? I am stuck with the same problem.

Comment: Did you update the sharelib after putting the jar ? `oozie admin -sharelibupdate` , the JAR should reflect in the `oozie admin -shareliblist hive` and also in the oozie launcher's stdout logs.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this error by placing my Serde JAR file in lib path of application.

Below is my HDFS directory structure:

```
/user/manoj/app/workflow.xml
/user/manoj/app/lib/json-serde-1.3-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

PS:  you may have any version of serDe JAR, I used `json-serde-1.3-jar-with-dependencies.jar` specifically because I found in other answer that this version supports deserialization as well and it worked for me. I was facing "cannot deserialize" error with hive-serde.jar.