# serdes jar don't work

Tags: hadoop, hive, hue, cloudera-cdh

I'm sing cdh5 quickstart... I would like to run this script:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE serd(
user_id string,
type string,
title string,
year string,
publisher string,
authors struct<name:string>,
source string)

   ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
   STORED AS  TEXTFILE;

   LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH '/user/hdfs/data/book-seded-workings-reduced.json/' INTO TABLE serd;
```

But I got this error:

Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. Could not initialize class org.openx.data.jsonserde.objectinspector.JsonObjectInspectorFactory

But following my previous question([Loading JSON file with serde in Cloudera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25149700/loading-json-file-with-serde-in-cloudera-and-how-working-with-json)) , I've tried to build each serd proposed here: https://github.com/rcongiu/Hive-JSON-Serde
But I always have the same error

Comment: On the left in 'settings' i add path to serde I use...I've tried to follow this link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22324106/serde-problems-with-hive-0-12-and-hadoop-2-2-0-cdh5-0-0-beta2    But it didn't work for me...So I think , maybe I didn't notice something

Comment: Have you tried the Json Serde from the Twitter Example? http://gethue.com/how-to-analyze-twitter-data-with-hue/

Comment: It worked...Thanks Romain... I changed my code to fit my data: CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE serd(
  user_id STRING,
  type STRING,
  title STRING,
  year STRING,
  publisher STRING,
  authors ARRAY<STRUCT<name:STRING>>,
  source STRING)
       
       ROW FORMAT SERDE 'com.cloudera.hive.serde.JSONSerDe'
       LOCATION '/user/hdfs/data/serd/'

Comment: But when I want to import my data it works , but I get an error when I want to see the sample...Is my script wrong to fit with my data?

Comment: Moreoer when I'm in Hive editor, on the left I can't see 'serd' table

Comment: :it works after a log out(but not refreshing the page) , but I'm still stuck with other problem: I can't see imported date and I get an error when trying a select statement in hive editor

Comment: It's okay , it works now...The only query I can't run is selec * from serd;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, only twitter serde worked in my cdh5 vm